# How to redirect from javascript-disabled page to the previous page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, browser

I am on a home page and my javascript is enabled. Now what I did, I disabled the javascript and refresh the `home.php` page then the page is redirecting on `javascript-disabled.php` page because I added the meta tag with URL. There is no issue till here.

My issue is,

I am on `javascript-disabled.php` and I enable the javascript and refresh the page but it's not redirecting on the previous page.

This is my URL when javascript is disabled.

```
http://localhost/example/javascript-disable.php
```

After enabling the javascript and refresh the page
 I got this URL `http://localhost/example/undefined`

I added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.location.href =  window.history.back();
</script>
```

**Home.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>home</title>
     <noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=javascript-disable.php" /></noscript>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <!--content her-->
    hi
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript-disable.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Javascrit disable</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
        <h2>Javascript is disabled.</h2>
        <p>Please enable javascript and refersh the page.</p>
        <p>To unable to javascript click <a href="#" target="_blank">here</a></p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     window.location.href =  window.history.back();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will be honest I am confused
For security purposes you cannot turn on and off JS with a script
As your HTML indicates the user has to enable the JS in the browser settings, However a anchor to a blank bookmark (href="#") wont refresh the page and wont enable JS.

This means the <script> further on down will be ignored by the browser as JS is unsupported or disabled at the time the page loaded which is when it reads the <script> tags.

Comment: @DataCure, Yes, My anchor tag is blank I haven't added the link here. If the user wants to know how to enable the javascript then They can click and read the guidelines to enable the script.

Comment: @DataCure, Yes  If the script is already disabled in the browser then my page will redirect on the javascript-disable.php page and there the user can read and click on the link to enable the script.

Comment: There is no "back" in window.history.back(); since javascript was disabled, you should try instead window.location.replace("http://example.com");

Comment: If User know how to enable the javascript the they can do directly without click on link. Once they enable the script and refresh the page then page directly redirect on previous page.

Comment: @elMiedo, It needs the previous page. It can be home,  it can be Aboutus, it can be Contacts etc.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this, but it's an interesting question. I think javascript doesn't record history when it is disabled. You should try to store the current page when user have javascript enabled in localstorage. When javascript is enable again, then you access to localstorage and get the previous page.

Comment: @elMiedo, because I have one registration form and static pages.  I set the client-side and server-side validation on the registration form which is working perfectly. But on my website, I am using some javascript code to look website good and best. If the script disables the website will not look good. So the page will redirect on javascript-disabled page

Comment: Alternate method:  if you're routing everything through one page, you could use css to show a "please enable javascript" message and hide all other content.  Then use javascript to hide the message and enable the content.

Comment: @TimMorton, an Alternate method is also good. I have to add the all the code on each page. Right? and I have more than 20 pages. that's the reason I am adding page URL with a meta tag.

Comment: If you're not using url rewriting and running everything through index.php, then yes, you would have to put this on each page.  If you're using a common header and footer, you could put it in one of those...

Comment: @TimMorton, Your suggestion is also good. I found my solution. I don't know that's the right way or not.

Comment: Depends on how much you want it to scale.  My approach is more typical of MVC thinking.  Good topic for study...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found my answer, I don't know it's best or not. Please suggest it's secure or not.

What I did, I added below code on the each page

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];//It will store the page name
```

and the javascript-disabled.php page  I added in the top

```
session_start();
$url = $_SESSION['url']; // holds url for last page visited.
```

At the bottom before closing body tag, I added

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var previous_page= '<?php echo $url; ?>';
window.location.href = previous_page;
</script>
```

and It's working perfectly.